# KitKat DownloadManager not returning correct COLUMN_REASON

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I am using DownloadManager to download files. I have a test that tries to download an invalid file and on my devices that are not KitKat when I do the the following for the file that does not exist on the internet:

```
String failError = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON));
```

I get the correct '404' as a string which I then convert to an int for checking against the known error codes.

However, on KitKat all I get is 'placeholder' as the error.

What's different about KitKat, and if COLUMN_REASON is now returning an int instead of an int wrapped in a string, what's the fix and why isn't this documented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> String failError =
>   c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON));

Change this as

int failError = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON));